# Why can I instantiate my C++ template?

Tags: templates, gcc

Not sure what the problem is..

$ g++ test2.C 
test2.C: In function 'int main()':
test2.C:25: error: call of overloaded 'swap(int&, int&)' is ambiguous
test2.C:8: note: candidates are: void swap(T&, T&) [with T = int]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:92: note:                 void std::swap(_Tp&, _Tp&) [with _Tp = int]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
inline void swap(T& i, T& j) { 
T temp = i; i = j; j = temp;
}




main() {
int m,n;
cout << "Enter integer :";

cin >> m;
cout << "Enter integer :";

cin >> n;
cout << m << "," << n << endl;

swap(m,n);

cout << m << "," << n << endl;
}
```

Comment: Instead of making your title unique by adding "(newbie)", choose a *real title* which describes your problem. Figure out why your problem is different from the existing question with the same title. If you can't figure that much out, your question is probably a duplicate and shouldn't be asked in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Try naming your swap myswap (or anything else) or putting it in a namespace

because you have `using namespace std;` it is confused between your swap and std::swap

In general always avoid `using namespace std;`  Definately in headers but as here, it can cause problems in .cpp files as well